# Getting character using fgetc

Tags: c

How do I know that c = fgetc(dict_ptr) will update c to get the next character in a file pointer named dictionary instead of any random character?[image: img src]

Comment: Please post code as text an not as an image - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: As for your question, are you asking how to check whether `fgetc` has an error or not? If so, you can get the answer from the [fgetc man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc): "fgetc(), getc() and getchar() return the character read as an unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on end of file or error."

Comment: Using `printf("");` is fairly weird — it prints nothing, of course, because the string is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this what you are asking, but whenever you are reading a character with fgetc, the file pointer (here: dict_ptr) will move one character forward. So c will always get the next character.